# Compiling an expression in a variable

Tags: compile

I'm trying to compile a rather long (takes quite some time to scroll through) expression that is in a variable but I'm unsure how it would be done in mathematica. I've tried the obvious

```
a=x^2;
Compile[{{x, _Real}}, a]
%[1]
```

or

```
x^2;
Compile[{{x, _Real}}, %]
%[1]
```

or

```
x^2;
Compile[{{xx, _Real}}, %/.{x->xx}]
%[1]
```

but they all give the same error:

```
CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression x^2 should be a machine-size real number.
```

, however pasting the expression into the compile function does work:

```
Compile[{{x, _Real}}, x^2]
%[1]
```

While this is possible for simple expressions that are fixed, my expression is rather long and may change as I slowly find more and more errors in it, so I'd prefer if it could be compiled.

Even after searching the [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html), seems like all the example has explicit expressions inside the compile function.

Does anyone know if it is possible to compile an expression stored in a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
a = x^2;
cf = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Evaluate@a]

cf[2]
(* 4 *)
```

`Compile` has the `HoldAll` attribute.

Comment: oh nice thanks!